# MS Access where in Missing operator

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I exclude the `IN` clause or the preceding conditions, the query works, but it does not work when I run as such:

```
SELECT * FROM Widgets  WHERE  wdg_weight >= 1 
AND  wdg_weight <= 22 
AND  wdg_length >= 1 
AND  wdg_length <= 22 
AND  wdg_ports <= 3 
AND  wdg_ports >= 5 
AND  wdg_function = 'Primary' 
AND  IN ('Black','Blue')
```

I get a Syntax Error Missing Operator error, and it displays the entire query in the error message....
Please point out where I am making mistakes

Comment: Should be: `AND wdg_function IN ('Black','Blue')`

Comment: @MichaelLiu oh thats it please post as answer

Comment: Wait... `wdg_function = 'Primary' AND wdg_function IN ('Black', 'Blue')`? That will always be false?

Comment: @Luke `wdg_color IN ('Black','Blue')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While giving a condition using IN clause you should specify in which column of the database the IN clause should look

eg:

```
Select * from students
    where name IN ('John','Jim')
```